# How to use WM_INPUT to detect continus mouse clicks?

Tags: c++, c, windows, opengl, raw-input

I am using WM_INPUT to detect my mouse updates, when I click my mouse button 1, I will detect that button 1 is down. However if i hold down the button, the subsequent updates for the mouse will show that button 1 is not depressed.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows that usButtonFlags can detect transition state of the mouse buttons. This means rawinput can detect the mouse at the time of press and release but cannot detect the pressed or released state of mouse buttons.

But is it possible for the rawinput to detect the pressed or released state of mouse buttons instead of a transition state?

I used OSG to render a full screen scene, thus, all the mouse clicks should be associated with the current window. I use eventTraversal function of osgViewer::Viewer to update the raw input data:

```
class CustomViewer : public osgViewer::Viewer
{
public:
    CustomViewer() : osgViewer::Viewer() {}
    virtual ~CustomViewer() {}

    virtual void eventTraversal()
    {
        RawInputEventRegistry::instance()->updateState( _eventQueue.get() );
        osgViewer::Viewer::eventTraversal();

    }
}

void RawInputEventRegistry::updateState( osgGA::EventQueue* eventQueue )
{
    MSG msg;
    if( GetMessage( &msg, c_handle, WM_INPUT, WM_INPUT ) != -1)
    { 
        HRAWINPUT test = (HRAWINPUT)msg.lParam;
               add_to_raw_mouse_x_and_y((HRAWINPUT)msg.lParam);

    } 

    osg::ref_ptr<RawInputEvent> event = new RawInputEvent;
    event->SetMouseData(raw_mice);
    eventQueue->userEvent( event.get() );
}
```

The add_to_raw_mouse_x_and_y() function is responsible for button click checking, such as:

```
if (raw->data.mouse.usButtonFlags & RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_DOWN) raw_mice[i].buttonpressed[0] = 1;
```

Comment: What's preventing you from tracking the state of the mouse buttons? It's not that those change volatilely without your process getting informed. Also DirectInput can do what you ask for.

Comment: When my clicks and releases are relatively slow, there will be no problem. But when I move my mouse on the window and release button fast, the system failed to track the state change. I think the problem is: when I move fast, the viewer need to update the image and when the button release was done during the frame update, then the system do not have the chance to detect the release signal.

Comment: If that happens you're doing something wrong. One of the core principles of an event based input system is, that either no event must be lost or that in case of loss the application gets informed about this. Windows is of the *no events are lost* kind. It would help if you pasted some source code. Namely your event retrieval and dispatch code.

Comment: What *can* happen is, if the mouse button gets release with the pointer outside of the window. However in that case you got a design bug in your program, because if you're depending on tracking the mouse state you should grab the pointer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I think the button release should be inside the window

Comment: I take it there's a reason you can't use `SetCapture()` and `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, because otherwise that would do exactly what you want.